# hex to bin converted and print in multiple rows

Tags: python

I am hardcoding the following function to decode hex to binanry. it does not look elegant as I want to be but it works. Can someone help me to generalize the code?

```
def print_hex_to_atp(hex,output_file):  

    if hex=="0":
        output_file.write("> Data   0 end;\n") #print hex 0 in binary
        output_file.write("> Data   0 end;\n") 
        output_file.write("> Data   0 end;\n") 
        output_file.write("> Data   0 end;\n")
    elif hex=="1":
        output_file.write("> Data   0 end;\n") #print hex 1 in binary
        output_file.write("> Data   0 end;\n") 
        output_file.write("> Data   0 end;\n") 
        output_file.write("> Data   1 end;\n")
    elif hex=="2":
        output_file.write("> Data   0 end;\n") #print hex 2 in binary
        output_file.write("> Data   0 end;\n") 
        output_file.write("> Data   1 end;\n") 
        output_file.write("> Data   0 end;\n")
    elif hex=="3":
        output_file.write("> Data   0 end;\n") #print hex 3 in binary
        output_file.write("> Data   0 end;\n") 
        output_file.write("> Data   1 end;\n") 
        output_file.write("> Data   1 end;\n")
    elif hex=="4":
        output_file.write("> Data   0 end;\n") #print hex 4 in binary
        output_file.write("> Data   1 end;\n") 
        output_file.write("> Data   0 end;\n") 
        output_file.write("> Data   0 end;\n")
    elif hex=="5":
        output_file.write("> Data   0 end;\n") 
        output_file.write("> Data   1 end;\n")
        output_file.write("> Data   0 end;\n") 
        output_file.write("> Data   1 end;\n")
    elif hex=="6":
        output_file.write("> Data   0 end;\n") 
        output_file.write("> Data   1 end;\n") 
        output_file.write("> Data   1 end;\n") 
        output_file.write("> Data   0 end;\n")

    else:
        c="invalid"
```

Comment: Why do you stop at six?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `bin` function and the `base` argument of `int`:

```
def hex_to_bin(h):
    return bin(int(h, 16))[2:]

example = "1a"

for binary_digit in hex_to_bin(example):
    print(binary_digit)
```

This has the output:

```
1
1
0
1
0
```

Note that this will throw a `ValueError` if you pass it an invalid hex string.

If you want it to be padded to the nearest [nibble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble), you can do:

```
def hex_to_bin(h):
    return "{:0{}b}".format(int(h, 16), len(h) * 4)
```

which will have the output:

```
0
0
0
1
1
0
1
0
```

As demonstrated, both of these work on arbitrary length hex strings, not just single digits.

Both of these work by first parsing the hex-string into an integer, using the `int` function, and then formatting that integer as binary. The second uses Python's `format` mini-language, specifying that the format (`:`) should be in binary (`b`), padded with zeroes (`0`), and it should be four times the length of the hex-string (`{}` -> `len(h) * 4`). The `{}` curly braces are used to indicate arguments given to `format`. The first uses the `bin` function, which is self-explanatory enough, but it has to do `[2:]` as the `bin` function adds `0b` to the start of the generated binary. `2:` slices that away.

It should be easy enough to reimplement into your original code. To do so, you would do something like this:

```
for digit in hex_to_bin(hex_s):
    output_file.write("> Data   {} end;\n".format(digit))
```

Note that I've renamed your variable `hex`. I'd recommend you do the same, as `hex` is a builtin Python function (this might get especially confusing if you plan to be working with hex).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `int(..,16)` to decode hexadecimal string into an integer. Furthermore you can for instance use a `for` loop to obtain the four different bits, like:

```
def print_hex_to_atp(hex,output_file):
    try:
        data = int(hex,16)
        if data < 16:
            for i in range(3,-1,-1):
                output_file.write("> Data   {} end;\n".format((data>>i) & 1))
        else:
            # do something in case the value is greater than 15
            pass
    except ValueError:
        # do something in case hex is not a valid hexadecimal string
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hex="4"
base_10 = int(hex,16)
bin = "{0:04b}".format(base_10)
print("0x{0:02x} -> 0b{0:04b}".format(base_10) )
for bit in bin:
    print("> data\t{0} end".format(bit))
```

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers

Comment: If you use the format specifier `:#03x`, you don't need to manually add an `0x`.